# How to find a point between two positions in euclidean space

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

Hello

I wish I had studied trigonometry more. Tried googling vector projection but I'm a bit lost. I have a Point A and a point B in euclidean space.

I want to be able to find any point using a length value on the line intersecting B. That line is always facing A as a side.

Is it tangent?

I'm lost.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you looking for exactly?

Comment: Hello, thanks for helping me out. Given 2 points, A and B on any given euclidean space, I want to be able to find any point in the sides of B which will always be intersecting an imaginary line parallel to one in B, I try to explain it here: https://i.imgur.com/H30fykC.png

Answer (score 0):

The angular coefficient for the line thorugh $A(x_a,y_a)$ and $B(x_b,y_b)$ is given by (assuming $x_b\neq x_a$)

$$m=\frac{y_b-y_a}{x_b-x_a}$$

then the angular coefficient for the line orthogonal to line $A-B$ is

$$m'=-\frac1m$$

finally the line through B perpendicular to line $A-B$ is

$$y-y_b=m'(x-x_b)$$

Comment: Hello, thanks for helping me out. Given 2 points, A and B on any given euclidean space, I want to be able to find any point in the sides of B which will always be intersecting an imaginary line parallel to one in B, I try to explain it here: https://i.imgur.com/H30fykC.png I will study what you just shared. Will come back with comments. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=(x_A,y_A)$ and $B=(x_B,y_B)$. Then the slope of the line passing through $AB$ is
$$\frac{y_B-y_A}{x_B-x_A}.$$
Therefore, the slope of the line passing through $B$ and perpendicular to $AB$ is
$$-\frac{x_B-x_A}{y_B-y_A}.$$
This perpendicular line passes through $B$, so its equation is
$$y-y_B=-\frac{x_B-x_A}{y_B-y_A}(x-x_B).\qquad (*)$$
Now, if some point $(x,y)$ is a distance $d$ away from $B$, then it is on the circle
$$(x-x_B)^2+(y-y_B)^2=d^2.\qquad (**)$$
This point will be on the line perpendicular to $AB$ and passing through $B$ whenever the circle $(**)$ intersects the line $(*)$. Therefore, we have to substitute $y$ from $(*)$ into the equation for the circle above, and now we can express $x$ only in terms of the coordinates $(x_B,y_B)$ and the distance $d$.

Once we have $x$, we can get $y$ by plugging back into $(*)$.